# How to assign default value for input type date by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, date, date-format

I can assign default value to input[type="date"] like this in php:

```
<input name="date" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

which is resulting into string:

`value="2015-03-09"`

and input even display this date in my local dateformat: `09.03.2015` (idk why, but it is great).

---

But if I want to assign default date value by javascript:

```
protocolDate = new Date(protocolDate.substr(0,4), protocolDate.substr(5,2), protocolDate.substr(8,2));
```

which is returning the same string and generating the same html: `value="2015-03-09"` input shows default value like this: `dd.mm.rrrr`. Is there a way how to assign default value for input type date by javascript?

Comment: have you considered changing the input value at document load?

Comment: timezone will help you for this.Try  with time zone

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that in my string were some whitespaces. Removing by trim() function solved the problem